# how to store images from different users on the website into oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to make a website which is for users to post something with pics.
So, I need to create tables using SQL in the oracle database.
however, I don't know how to store images from different users into a database.

there were some ways which were to store image path and retrieve images using image pate when it's needed.
but, every user has a different path. their images exist only in their computers.

how do I solve this problem?

I'm a very beginner at the database system. please tell me what data type I need to use and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is to store pictures on database table.

You should use BLOB (Binary Large Object) which is perfect for storing multimedia content like images.

Here you can find some more info about it:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28845/ch7.htm#i1037547

Comment: As for "store image path and retrieve images using image pate when it's needed. but, every user has a different path. their images exist only in their computers." .. the databsase has no ability to connect to client computers.  You will have to have a method to upload the image file to the db server so that you can store it as a blob column in a database table.